# Selenium Selectors and Input not working. Suggestions?

Tags: python, selenium

Im using Selenium (Python) and am trying to log myself into the discord Website (https://discordapp.com/login) but all my code does is load the page and thats it. I tried all, Css selectors, XPath EVERYTHING. Does anyone have suggestions?

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://discordapp.com/login')
assert 'discordapp' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='email']")
elem.send_keys("itsolidude@gmail.com")

elem1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")
elem1.send_keys("password" + Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code, where I added the synchronization and tested on Firefox using 
python.

You have to add the below import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Code:

```
url = "https://discordapp.com/login"
driver.get(url)
email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='email']")))
email.send_keys("test@test.com")
```

Comment: Doing this posts errors 'unresolved reference ''wait" '

Comment: My bad forget to add imports part to the post.

Comment: Ye i assumed there were imports missing :P , but the "wait" one is sill throwing, would u mind posting the whole script reeal quick? i dont know what im doing wrong , might be that late time :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193433/discussion-between-supputuri-and-itsolidude).

Answer (score 0):

#### If you wanna log in on discord server using selenium(python)then you can use my code

**Just add your credentials in the code :)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
time.sleep(6)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username_input.send_keys("enter-your-username-here")


password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys("Enter-your-password-here")


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
login_button.click()
```